# Virtual environment not correctly getting created in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a virtual environment using python in order to work with selenium. I am running the following command to create the virtual environment

```
python.exe –m venv %USERPROFILE%\venvs\demoenv
```

However, I am having an issue. The environment does get created but since, my username is with a whitespace `for example: Stack Overflow`, the path to the environment that gets created is something like this:

```
C:\Users\Stack
```

It creates a new username in my Users folder in C drive. I have also tried doing something like this

```
python.exe –m venv Users\Stack Overflow\venvs\demoenv
```

Despite this, it still creates an environment in the following path

```
C:\Users\Stack
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `python.exe –m venv "Users\Stack Overflow\venvs\demoenv"`

Whenever the directory or file has a whitespace in its name, you need to put it in quotes.

the above works well in cmd, however on powershell, i found that only that specific directory needs to be in quotes.

So, `python.exe –m venv Users\"Stack Overflow"\venvs\demoenv`

Answer (score 0):

Please pass the path inside `"` (double quotes).

Below is the result of what I tried myself :-

```
C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop>mkdir Stack Overflow
C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS

 Directory of C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop

22-05-2021  22:05    <DIR>          .
22-05-2021  22:05    <DIR>          ..
22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          Stack Overflow
               0 File(s)     23,825,138 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  102,416,990,208 bytes free
```

---

```
C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop>python -m venv "./Stack Overflow/"

C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop>cd "Stack Overflow"

C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop\Stack Overflow>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS

 Directory of C:\Users\PRATAPALOK\Desktop\Stack Overflow

22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          .
22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          ..
22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          Include
22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          Lib
22-05-2021  22:06               170 pyvenv.cfg
22-05-2021  22:06    <DIR>          Scripts
               1 File(s)            170 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  102,421,467,136 bytes free
```